# Unreal Engine 4: How to load an audio file from a external folder in runtime?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to access a wav file in runtime and play it from an external folder. I can't import it as an asset in the editor because the file is being generated by an external program in another folder.

I've tried using the StaticLoadObject function but it always searchs inside the content folder and ignores an absolute path.

I've checked VictoryPlugin but the function it provides for loading objects in runtime only applies to the content folder too.

In all the forums I have checked people refer to VictoryPlugin or there are no answers to the questions other people have asked, but there must be a way of accessing external folders from C++ code, because I'm able to load a JSON file with LoadFileToString and create a process with CreateProc, but can't find a way to load an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something Unreal natively supports, and you're not generally able to use Editor code (which includes asset import code) at runtime.

Your best bet is the Marketplace for plugins, and it looks like there's a free plugin that does what you want: https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/runtime-audio-importer